# protected $var = null; vs protected $var;

Tags: php, variables, null, initialization

I am wondering if there is a difference between the two lines of code below:

```
protected $var = null;
protected $var;
```

I have seen both being used, and am wondering if it is just a matter of preference, (aka `$var;` initializes the variables to `null` anyway) or if there is actually a tangible difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same thing. It's merely a stylistic difference.

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php:

A variable is considered to be null if:

- it has been assigned the constant NULL.
- **it has not been set to any value yet.**
- it has been unset().

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I had looked under [php.net documentation on variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) but not the documentation on the null type!